# On the external product of a real normed space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E$ a real normed space. If $X\subset E$ and $A\subset\mathbb R$ are closed. What about the subset of $E$ : $AX=\{ax \mid a\in A; x\in X\}$? closed or not?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to be closed. Lets take $E = \mathbb C$. Then we define $I=\{ [0,2\pi)\cap\mathbb Q \}$, then we can take a ordering $\{\varphi_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ of all elements in $I$. Then we take $X=\{k\cdot e^{i\varphi_k}\}$, which is closed in $E= \mathbb C$. Then we choose $A=\mathbb R$. The resulting set $AX=\{ r\cdot e^{i\varphi}\mid r \in (-\infty,\infty); \varphi \in I \}$ is not closed in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: $AX$ is not *open* in $\mathbb{C}$ (just like $I$ is not open in $[0, 2\pi)$) but it is not closed either. Perhaps you meant $AX$ is dense? Otherwise you can simplify the construction by restricting to $I = \{1/k\}$ and $X = \{ke^{i/k}\}$.

Comment: Thank you, I meant it is not closed. But clearly it is not open either. Thx